# Ginger precipitation

Tags: ginger

I make a ginger in alcohol product and am having a problem that I though you could help with. I juice fresh ginger root through a standard juicer, discarding the solids, then let it settle in the fridge for 24 hours to let the remaining fibrous component settle out. After mixing with alcohol, either there is additional precipitate in the solution (not really solid and can't be strained; it's more of a floating conglomerate) or the ginger layers out.

Do you have any tricks to make the ginger more soluble in alcohol? Is this a pH thing or is the alcohol precipitating additional solids on its own irrespective of pH?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "can't be strained", do you mean that the cloudiness remains even if you pour it through filter paper?

Comment: What are you trying to make? Ginger-flavored alcohol, or something specific?

Comment: It sounds like the ginger might be floculating, aka 'type 2 settling' or other slower settling (type 3 or 4).  (warning, if you search for those terms, you'll find information about water treatment plants).  The only real trick is to wait it out, and decant, or try to put enough other particulates in there to push it all down faster.  If it's type 3, you *might* be able to neutralize the charge on the particles so they'll fall faster, but that's going to ruin your food.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not simply infuse your alcohol with ginger? Its slower, but effective. It doubles as a way to store fresh ginger.

If I'm peeling some ginger, I'm peeling an entire "thumb" of ginger and storing the peeled slices in vodka in a mason jar. The ginger keeps for at least 2 months, though it's never been around for that long. I read about the technique from [Fine Cooking](http://www.finecooking.com/articles/storing-ginger.aspx).

After a few weeks to a month, I have ginger-infused vodka.